# Distance of subshells from nucleus

Tags: orbitals, atomic-structure, atomic-radius

Which subshell is more closer to the nucleus.4f or 6s?
6s gets filled first so does it have to be more closer to the nucleus?

Comment: Distance of sub shells to nucleus cannot be determined as subshells are not points. They are extending around the whole atom. Their energies can be measured. But not their distances to the nucleus. Forget about Bohr's model !

Comment: Then how do you explain lanthanide contraction?

Answer (score 5):

The question is misguided by the obsolete idea of shells and subshells as separated exclusive regions of the space around the nucleus.

All orbitals largely overlaps and statistical distribution of electron density, (aside of being in the particular orbital) depends on the nucleus charge and overall electron configuration.

It can be said, that distribution of electrons density for 4f is in average closer to the nucleus than for 6s. But due weak screening of f electrons, the effective nucleus charge for outermost ekectrons is growing across the lanthanoid serie, what leads to the contraction.

OTOH, higher s orbitals have very significant density near nucleus as the local maximum, what leads to relativistic effects due high speed., especially for the near right end of the period 6. And, this is reportedly responsible for about 10% of lanthanoid contraction.